# Wordpress website not opening after duplicating on local server

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I deployed my website from server to my local machine using duplicator plugin. The deployment was successful (no errors). However when I am trying to open the website I get a blank page.

I am using latest version of MAMP server on windows machine. When I try to open http://localhost:8888, I automatically get redirected to http://localhost which is a blank page. Though I am able to access the dashboard through http://localhost:8888/wp-admin. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1- create index.html file with any text on your local server and try to access it via http://localhost to see if local server is working fine.
2- you need to export mySQL database from website & import to local mySQL server, because on server database urls and names are different.